# Enums Ordinal in Obj-C (using enums for Z Values in Cocos2D)

Tags: objective-c, enums, cocos2d-iphone, ordinal

I want to avoid manually assigning random Z values for Layers/Nodes in Cocos2D and planning on using enums for it.

I know enums are ordinal-ordered but is it ***safe to rely*** on the enum ordering in Obj-C/Cocos2D?

For eg, is it safe to do something like

enum {
kZValMIN,
kZValLayer1,
kZValLayer2,
........
kZValLayerN,
kZValMAX
}

when I want LayerN top-most and Layer1 at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

In addition you can assign specific values and the enumeration of following objects continue from that value:

```
enum { 
kZValMIN, 
kZValLayer1 = 10,
kZValLayer2 = 20, 
........ 
kZValLayerN = 100, 
kZValMAX, 
}
```

kZValMAX would then be 101.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, Steffen! BTW, thanks for the awesome book too - that is helping a lot.